# Getting uniqe elements of the list in the following pattern

Tags: sorting, tcl

I am trying to get lsort command with following behaviour,Lets say i have a variable &

```
set variable {a a a a b b b b c c c c }
```

desired output is

```
a b c d
```

if variable is

```
set variable { b b  d d c c c c }
```

desired output is

```
b d c
```

if variable is

```
set variable { z z z a a a b b  }
```

desired output is

```
z a b
```

basically i want unique elements of the list but the one which is repeated first should occur first in the output & the one which is repeated last should be present at last . Above are the possible scenarios of my case

I have tried lsort - unique   . but this is sorting based on alhabatical order.

Your help is appreciated

PS : my variable contains the elements repeated for sure , the elements which are repeated at first will not be repeated again at last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `proc` to do that (Tcl8.5 and later):

```
proc lunique {l} {
    set result {}
    foreach i $l {
        if {$i ni $result} {lappend result $i}
    }
    return $result
}
```

For versions before 8.5, you would use `[lsearch $result $i] == -1` instead of `$i ni $result`.

If the list is *really* long, you might consider this one which avoids the lookup within the list and exploits the fact that you don't have strings appearing again after a different string:

```
proc lunique {l} {
    set previous ""
    foreach i $l {
        if {$previous != $i} {
            lappend result $i
            set previous $i
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Usage:

```
set newvariable [lunique $variable]
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are ideal for this (provided you want exact string comparison between the list elements) because they are order preserving.

```
proc uniques {theList} {
    set d {} 
    foreach item $theList {dict incr d $item}
    return [dict keys $d]
}
```

Then we can do:

```
set newvariable [uniques $variable]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set a {a a s s d d e e f f g g}
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $a]} {incr i} {
    set j [expr $i + 1]
    if {[string equal [lindex $a $i] [lindex $a $j]] == 1} {
       continue
    } else {
       lappend b [lindex $a $i]
    }
}
puts $b
```